# How can I create a Google Visualization intensity/heat map using a KMZ document?

Tags: kml, google-visualization, heatmap, kmz

I'd like to create a [Google Visualization API intensity/heat map](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/intensitymap.html) based on UK counties.

To do this, it appears that I need to use a custom KML/KMZ file that contains the county mapping data (which I've located).

Could anyone provide me with a sample of how I can display an intensity map based on a KMZ file? I know how to display Google Visualization intensity maps in general. I just can't find any examples that use a custom KMZ file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the example here:  http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032332

1.) Use Google Fusion Tables and import your KML file as a new table (boundaries of your shapes).  I use this free program (Shp2kml - http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html), which takes Shapefiles and converts to Google Earth KML files.

2.) Use Google Fusion Tables and import your data file (the column that determines the 'intensity')

3.) Merge the Tables

4.) Google Fusion Tables > Visualize > Map

5.) 'Configure Styles' > Change your bucket values (so that 0 to 1 displays as this color, 1 to 10 displays as that color, etc.)